# Decompress the Gzip json data in .Net Controller

Tags: c#, compression, gzip, gzipstream

I'm currently trying to decompress the json data that being passed in from the server side in the controller but keep hitting below error.

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.'

Below is the ajax code that pass in the json data to the controller.

```js
function SaveQuestion(jsonData, formId, parentId, message, flatJsonData, isSaveAndCreate) {
    $('#overlay2').show();
    // Compress the JSON data using gzip
    var compressedJsonData = pako.gzip(jsonData, { to: 'string' });

    // Base64 encode the compressed data
    var encodedCompressedJsonData = btoa(compressedJsonData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/IntelCollection/SaveDynamicForm",
        type: "POST",
        data: { formId: formId, jsonData: encodedCompressedJsonData, flatJsonData: flatJsonData, parentId: parentId },
        success: function (result) {
            if (isTest) {
                isTest = false;
                $('#tree').jstree(true).refresh();
                goForwardToCard3();
            }

            if (!isSaveAndCreate) {
                if (!isGoBack) {
                    refreshNodeId = result;
                }
                else {
                    isGoBack = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                refreshNodeId = 0;
            }

            $('#overlay2').hide();
            $("#tree").jstree(true).refresh();
            ReloadPreView();
            GrowlMessage(message, 'success');
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    });`
}
```

And below is the controller that received the data

```cs
public async Task<string> SaveDynamicForm(int formId, string jsonData, string flatJsonData, string parentId = "", string optionId = "")
{
         // Call the Decompress method to get the decompressed JSON data
         string decompressedJson = Decompress(jsonData);

         var treeModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TreeModel>(decompressedJson);
}
```

and this is the function that handle the compressed data

```cs
public static string Decompress(string value)
{
      byte[] compressedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
      string decompressedJson = "";

      using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes))
      using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
      using (MemoryStream decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
          // Decompress the data
          decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);

          // Convert the decompressed bytes to a string
          decompressedJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedStream.ToArray());

      }
      return decompressedJson;
}
```

I did try to use different type of decompress method such as GzipStream but still got similar issue. It seems no issue when encode and decode the data. So, i assuming the decompress function is not a right one. Do you guys have any insight on this?

Comment: You need GZipStream instead of DeflateStream in the C# code since you are using gzip when compressing it in the javascript.

Comment: I did use GzipStream as i mentioned in the comment but still hit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error says that the server cannot handle the gzip method, what I can recommend you to do is:
On the server side you use the decompression method that properly handles gzip. An example would be the GZipStream class.

```
public ActionResult GenericMethod(string formId, string jsonData, string flatJsonData, string parentId)
{
    byte[] compressedData = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonData);
    
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(compressedData))
    using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
    {
        string decompressedJsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Treat how to best find json data
    }
}
```

Comment: i got another error which is "EndOfStream = 'reader.EndOfStream' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException'" when use below approach. @https://stackoverflow.com/users/18524100/felipe-gabriel-souza-martins